# Angular 11, Router-outlet and routes children inside another child. Does not show component

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, router-outlet, angular11

I have problems with the routes and with child components within another child that are not displayed on the screen when I click on a button. I think it is a syntax problem but I can't see it. I appreciate your help.

app.routes.ts file:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes }    from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent }           from "./components/home/home.component";
import { CrearAvisoComponent }     from "./components/contenido/crear-aviso/crear-aviso.component";
import { SesionComponent }         from "./components/contenido/sesion/sesion.component";

//child components
import { SesionCuentaComponent }   from "./components/contenido/sesion-cuenta/sesion-cuenta.component";
import { SesionMensajesComponent } from "./components/contenido/sesion-mensajes/sesion-mensajes.component";

//sub-child components
import { SesionMsjInComponent }    from  "./components/contenido/sesion-mensajes/sesion-msj-in/sesion-msj-in.component";
import { SesionMsjSendComponent }  from  "./components/contenido/sesion-mensajes/sesion-msj-in/sesion-msj-in.component";



const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'home',        component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'crear-aviso', component: CrearAvisoComponent },
  { path: 'sesion',      component: SesionComponent, children: [
    { path: 'sesion-cuenta',   component: SesionCuentaComponent, outlet: 'sesionr'},
    { path: 'sesion-mensajes', component: SesionMensajesComponent, outlet: 'sesionr', children: [
        { path: 'sesion-msj-in',   component: SesionMsjInComponent, outlet: 'mensajesr'},
        { path: 'sesion-msj-send', component: SesionMsjSendComponent, outlet: 'mensajesr'},
        { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/sesion/(sesionr:sesion-avisos)/(mensajesr:sesion-mjs-in)'},
    ]}, 
    { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/sesion/(sesionr:sesion-avisos)' }
  ]},
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' }
];


export const APP_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)
```

html file:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/sesion', {outlets:{sesionr: ['sesion-avisos', {outlets:{mensajesr: ['sesion-msj-in'] }}] }}]">Send</a>

<router-outlet>
   <router-outlet name="sesionr">
      <router-outlet name="mensajesr"></router-outlet>
   </router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
```

The declaration in app.module.ts is correct because I have other routes that do work.
When I click the button it redirects me to 'SesionComponent' but i want to go to 'SesionMsjInComponent'.

Note: The folder of the components 'SesionMsjInComponent ' and 'SesionMsjSendComponent ' I put them in the folder component 'SesionMensajesComponent '

Comment: I dont know what is the problem. I would try to find a problem by elimanting routes by commenting them out. I think it would make more sense to put each subroutes in their own module. That might help you find solution.

Comment: I did what you told me. Remove the component folder and update all paths, but I still have the same problem

Comment: And the console does not give me errors